does ここから君と話せて make sense?
I'm trying to translate "being able to talk to you from here"
"here" is a metaphor, not a real physical place. it's a way of portraying distance between two persons. (me and an ex partner) we once were really close and now for the sake of our wellbeing we're casual friends
the feeling is something like this: I should be glad I at least get to talk to you and share some time even though it cannot be the same as before, I can't help it but want to connect as we used to do.
the full sentence is kinda depressing but can help understanding the situation that's being talked about better:
"if only I could settle for this, being able to talk to you from here"
thanks beforehand for your answers, hope I explained myself well :)

If "here" refers to someone's current standpoint or social position rather than a physical location, translating it as ここから話す would probably be confusing. If there is a perfect context between two native speakers, it could be possible to communicate using just ここから, but if you're not confident, it's wise not to choose this approach. You usually need to choose an unambiguous phrase, like この立場で話す or この立ち位置から話す.

this helped a lot, thank you !!!
